# Update MongoDB Document in VB.NET with the C# Driver

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, mongodb

I am having problems updating a document in MongoDB using VB.NET & the C# Driver.

I have code returning the document I wish to update but I'm not sure of the syntax to continue

```
Imports MongoDB.Bson
Imports MongoDB.Driver
Imports MongoDB.Driver.Builders

Dim mongo As MongoServer = MongoServer.Create()
mongo.Connect()
Dim db = mongo.GetDatabase("database")
Dim stock = db.GetCollection(Of BsonDocument)("stock")

Dim getDocument = New QueryDocument("productName", "test")
```

Answer (score 0):

See this page on how to do the update:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-parameter

Answer (score 0):

Use the coll.update method. e.g. to set the value of a field

```
Dim client = New MongoClient()
Dim db = client.GetServer().GetDatabase("test")
Dim coll = db.GetCollection("vbtest")
Dim productQuery = Query.EQ("productName", "test")
Dim updateStmt = Update.Set("cost", 3000)
coll.Update(productQuery, updateStmt)
```

More information on the methods can be found at http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/1.8.1/. Also I would recommend going through the tutorials at http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/csharp/. The examples are in C# though

Answer (score 0):

My solution, you can use same this block code:

```
Imports MongoDB.Bson
Imports MongoDB.Driver
```

Connect to Mongodb:

```
public client As MongoClient = New MongoClient("mongodb://user:password@IP:27017/MyDatabase")
public mydb As IMongoDatabase = client.GetDatabase("MyDatabase")
public userCollection As IMongoCollection(Of BsonDocument) = mydb.GetCollection(Of BsonDocument)("users")
```

Update:

```
Dim filterById = Builders(Of BsonDocument).Filter.Eq(Of String)("_id", userId)
userCollection.UpdateOne(filterById, New BsonDocument("$set", New BsonDocument("emailField", newEmail)))
```

Goodluck!