# update mongoDB from vb.net

Tags: vb.net, mongodb

I'm trying to update 'seats' collection in 'flight' database

```
    Dim mongo As MongoServer = MongoServer.Create()
    mongo.Connect()
    Dim db As MongoDatabase = mongo.GetDatabase("test")
    Dim coll = db.GetCollection("flights")
     Dim __foo As New QueryDocument
        __foo("name") = flight.ToString
        Dim _succ = coll2.FindOne(__foo)
        If Not _succ Is Nothing Then
            Dim _foo As BsonElement = _succ.GetElement("seats")
            Dim strfoo = _foo.Value.ToString
            Dim intfoo = Integer.Parse(strfoo)
            intfoo -= seats
            Dim __intfoo As New QueryDocument
            __intfoo("seats") = intfoo.ToString
            coll2.Update(__foo, __intfoo)       ' <--- the error
```

This code throws invalid cast exception at last line says, bsondocument cant be converted to imongoQuery

Comment: What's the content of `__intfoo`? You's better print it to check.

Comment: the content is'nt the problem, the problem is syntax of .Update() method , it accepts iMongoUpdate and i dont know how to write the correct syntax

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16676269/update-mongodb-document-in-vb-net-with-the-c-sharp-driver) maybe help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declaring _intfoo as UpdateDocument worked! thanks!